# How to download the saved images in the Hackspace cloud server?

Tags: linux, centos6

I wonder if someone know how could I download the saved images in a cloud server of Hackspace. I have been searching and nothing found even in the Hackspace knowledge base. I know it is stored in the file system, but where exactly is it?

If I download my images from the server, I can save disk space, and if one day (I hope never) I really need to restore from the image, I can easily upload the image back. But this information in hackspace is so obscure. I just do not want to open an ticket/support to ask only this question, and I hope someone else has had the same problem and help me out.

I'm using centOS 6.4, any help I will be very thankful. I mean if you guys know where in the file system the image is stored, it's all I need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided at serverfault.com and solved the problem. There is not a way to download the server image. ;'(

https://serverfault.com/questions/562858/how-to-download-the-saved-images-in-the-rackspace-cloud-server

I think here was the wrong place to ask this question! ;-)